# In react native, on executing posenet.load() getting error --> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'env().platform.fetch')

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Posenet has started giving an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'env().platform.fetch'), on calling the posenet.load().
```

It used to work fine until last week.

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as posenet from "@tensorflow-models/posenet";
import "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";

async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready();
    await posenet.load();
}
```

Below are the versions:

```
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"@tensorflow-models/posenet": "2.2.1",
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "2.7.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "0.5.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by deleting project, cloning it again and only running yarn instead of trying npm and yarn.